# Strange behavior of #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define d 10+10
int main()
{
    printf("%d",d*d);
    return 0;
}
```

As 10+10=20, I thought that d would be 20 everywhere in the program. But when I execute d*d, I have expected the result to be d*d=20*20=400. But the result gets printed as 120. Can anyone give me an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Macros like this are a simple find & replace.

Comment: The behaviour is not strange, it is exactly what is expected. Macros do textual substitution. d*d -> 10+10*10+10. Of course, any experienced programmer would see the macro definition and put parentheses around 10+10. Or change it to an enum, or const int.

Comment: A nice example of why macro's and arithmetic don't mix well... just like `#define SQUARE(n) n*n`, is rather unpredictable if used like this `SQUARE(++i)`

Comment: I think is 120 not 400. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preprocessor is just doing simple "find & replace", so this code:

```
printf("%d",d*d);
```

changes to

```
printf("%d",10+10*10+10);
```

which is 10+100+10 = 120

That's why it's so important to add parens in defines:

```
#define d (10+10)
```

Comment: Just one thing, the "find & replace" analogy is correct for most cases, but keep in mind that the Preprocessor is more powerful (and dangerous) than that.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d",d*d);
```

Here d is replaced as `printf("%d",10+10*10+10)`. so in this case it first executes `10*10` and adds with `10+100+10`. so results 120.

To eliminate this-

```
#define d (10+10) // FIX
int main()
{
   printf("%d",d*d);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#define d 10+10
```

to

```
#define d (10+10)
```

What you get without the proper parentheses is `10+10*10+10`  which is the same as `10 + (10 * 10) + 10`

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%d",d*d)` will evaluate (after preprocessing) to `printf("%d", 10+10*10+10);`